# My react app gives an error for some reason

Tags: reactjs, debugging

Error:

```
src\images\navbar.js
  Line 2:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "from" (2:11)

src\navbar.js
  Line 2:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "from" (2:11)
```

the project on GitHub: https://github.com/PufflyMan/airbnb-exp-clone

It's pretty straightforward code but no matter what I tried, I couldn't fix it. Thanks for attention!

Comment: Are you still having this error? I see no issue in your code.

Comment: yeah, it just fixed. I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

It just fixed itself. I didn't do anything